# Выбор select по имени и в соответствии с этим именем вывод из БД значений

Tags: php, mysqli

В таблице komp лежат данные о компаниях, она связана с таблицей gruz, где лежат данные о грузах по id_komp(в табл. gruz. Нужно, чтобы из таблицы komp была выборка имен компаний и после выбора определенной имени компании из таблицы gruz вытаскивалась информация о всех грузах этой компании. Я пыталась сделать так как-то, но не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

```
   <?php
    session_start();

    include_once("Connection.php");
     ?>

    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
    {
      include_once("header.php");
    }else{
      include_once("header/header_admin_1.php");
    }
     ?>

    <form action="" method="get"> 
<table>
<td>Компания</td>
<td>
    <select name="id">
    <?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `kompania`');
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "\t\t<option value=\"{$result['id']}\">{$result['name']}</option>\n";
    }?>
    </select>
</td>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

     <?php
    require_once 'BDconnect.php'; // Подключаем БД из файла

    $result = $_GET['id']; // Получаем параметр GET, который передали

    // table - название Вашей таблицы
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `gruz` WHERE `id`=$result"; // Ваш запрос в БД(поиск записи по id)

    $req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $req->bindValue(':id', $result, PDO::PARAM_STR); //Данные, которые передаёте в запрос
    $req->execute();
    $array = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Возвращаем значение.
    ?>


    <table style="margin-right: 700px; margin-top: 20px;"  border='1' align="right" width="20%" cellpadding="28" cellspacing="0" > 


    <?php
    if($array) { // Выводим данные
     echo "<td>№ секции <td>{$array['id']}</tr>";
     echo "<td>Название книги <td>{$array['id_upac']}</tr>";
     echo"<td>Автор <td>{$array['id_hran']}</tr>";
     echo "<td>Издание <td>{$array['id_komp']}</tr>";
     echo "<td>Год публикации <td>{$array['ves']}</tr>";
     echo"<td>Жанр <td>{$array['name']}</tr>";
     echo "<td>Количество страниц <td>{$array['rezmer']}</tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Для начала нужно сделать форму

Comment: Форму сделала. да..

Comment: Редактируйте код в вопросе чтобы мы тоже эту форму увидели.

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = $_GET['id']; // Получаем параметр GET, который передали

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `gruz` WHERE id_komp=?";
$req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$req->bind_param(?, $result);
$req->execute();
$array = $req->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQI_ASSOC);
```

в переменной $array у нас обычный массив который мы перебираем с помощью обычного оператора foreach